# parse XML TV listings, find out what is playing now

Tags: php, xml

i have an XML file of TV listings, TV.xml:

```
http://wklej.to/j4GQm
```

I would like to create some kind of epg for website from this. As i have no experience, it is unfortunately hard for me. I would like to get specific channel data, then compare it to the actual time, and show what is playing now on this channel (and what will play afterwards).

What i try:

```
 <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("TV.xml");
$me = "sub-title";
foreach($xml->programme as $item){
    echo "Start : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime(substr($item["start"], 0,  -6))) . '<br>';
    echo "End : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime(substr($item["stop"], 0,  -6))) . '<br>';
    echo "Channel : ".$item["channel"]. "<br>";
    echo "Title : ".$item->title. "<br>";
    echo "Info : ".$item->$me. "<br>";
    echo "Description : ".$item->desc. "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

So i would have a list of channels. But how do I show the specific channel info? Not the whole list. And the most important, how to compare it with the actual time and show only the program that is playing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already successfully parsed the programme information, so parsing the channel data should be easy. You may want to save the channel names in an array so you can replace the ID in `$item["channel"]` with the channel names. You could do something like this:

```
$channels = array();

foreach ($xml->channel as $c) {
    # convert these values to strings for storing in the array
    $channels[ $c['id']->__toString() ] = $c->{'display-name'}->__toString();
}
```

This gives an array of the form:

```
Array
(
    [TVPuls.pl] => TV Puls
    [TVPuls2.pl] => TV Puls 2
    ...
)
```

To find what's playing at the moment, the simplest thing is to format the current date and time in the same format that they are displayed in the listings, and then find out which programmes have a start and end time that covers the current time:

```
$time = date( "YmdHi" );  // e.g. 201410291949

# we'd be looking for start times less than $time and end times greater than $time
```

Put these together with your previous code, and only print out programmes that are on right now:

```
$channels = array();
foreach ($xml->channel as $c) {
    $channels[ $c['id']->__toString() ] = $c->{'display-name'}->__toString();
}

$time = date( "YmdHi" );

foreach($xml->programme as $item) {
# or to search for programmes on a specific channel only:
# foreach($xml->xpath('programme[@channel="TVPuls.pl"]') as $item) {

    $start = substr( (string)$item["start"], 0, -8);
    $end   = substr( (string)$item["stop"], 0, -8);
    # if the time is right...
    if ($time > $start && $time < $end) {
        echo "Start : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime($start)) . '<br>';
        echo "End : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime($end)) . '<br>';
        # the channel has to be converted to a string to use as an array key
        echo "Channel : ". $channels[ $item["channel"]->__toString() ]. "<br>";
        echo "Title : ".$item->title. "<br>";
        # put braces and quotes around element names with a hyphen in them
        echo "Info : ".$item->{'sub-title'}. "<br>";
        echo "Description : ".$item->desc. "<br>";
    }
}
```

Output for channel TV Puls:

Start : 19:50 29.10.2014
End : 20:55 29.10.2014
Channel : TV Puls
Title : Spartakus: Zemsta: Miejsce w świecie
Info : [serial historyczny]  (Spartacus: Vengeance: A Place in this World) (Ep.2) (2012) (USA)
Description : Spartakus i jego towarzysze wędrują na południe imperium. Wkrótce przejmują należącą do Rzymian willę, w której przez pewien czas mieszkała Naevia. Kobieta została już jednak odesłana w inne miejsce. Pod osłoną nocy jeden z niewolników, mężczyzna o imieniu Tyberiusz, próbuje zabić Spartakusa. Zachwycony jego odwagą tracki wojownik nie zabija śmiałka, lecz postanawia przyjąć go w szeregi swoich ludzi i wyszkolić. Po powrocie do Kapui Lukrecja otrzymuje wiadomość od tajemniczego nieznajomego. Wkrótce wychodzi na jaw, że informacja pochodziła od Ashura, z którym kobieta potajemnie współpracuje
W Rzymie wciąż trwa bunt gladiatorów. Mieszkańcy boją się, jakie będą tego konsekwencje. Chcąc stłumić powstanie i uspokoić obywateli, Gajusz Klaudiusz Glaber (Craig Parker) udaje się razem ze swoją armią do Kapui. Liczy, że na miejscu spacyfikuje grupę zdesperowanych niewolników. Ich dowódcą jest Spartakus (Liam McIntyre), który waha się, jaką drogę powinien teraz wybrać
Jesse Warn
Liam McIntyre, Dustin Clare, Manu Bennett, Lucy Lawless

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best. If i could ask 1 more question... if i would like to show only one output, for example TV Puls (the whole rest hide), how to modify the code?

Comment: The quick and easy way would be to use an XPath to pull out the entries from the channel you're interested in: replace `foreach($xml->programme as $item)` with `foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="TVPuls.pl"]' ) as $item)` -- that will search for all `programme` elements where the attribute `channel` is `TVPuls.pl`.

Comment: How if i would like to check what will be next, after the program which is going now?

Comment: @user3412188 You have the end time of your current programme, so you can search for programmes on the same channel where the start time equals the end time of the current programme (e.g. if `$ch` is the channel and `$end` is the end time--search with `$xml->xpath('programme[@channel=$ch and @start=$end]')`). If that doesn't turn up any results, you could parse the date and then look for the closest date/time.