# Get icon from XML URL

Tags: php, xml

I am creating some EPG for the website. I do not have experience. Unfortunately, I'm finding it difficult. How can I get the icons, what is wrong in this code?`

```
Final code working:

    <?php
     $url = 'XML URL LINK';
     $xml=simplexml_load_file("$url");  
     $progs = $xml->xpath('//programme');
     foreach ($progs as $prog) {
       $title = $prog->xpath('./title/text()')[0];
       $link = (count($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))>0) ? ($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))[0] : ("No icon");
       echo "Logo: <img src='{$link}'> <br/>" ;
       echo "Title : ".$title. "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should get you close to what I think you are trying to do. Note that not all programs have associated logos.

```
$progs = $xml->xpath('//programme');

foreach ($progs as $prog) {
    $title = $prog->xpath('./title/text()')[0];
    $link = (count($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))>0) ? ($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))[0] : ("No icon");
    echo($title .": ".  $link);
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

**EDIT**:

I'm still not entirely sure I understand what you want, but it sounds like you need to wrap the whole thing in html and output to a browser. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
         $url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HelmerLuzo/TDTChannels_EPG/master/TDTChannels_EPG.xml';
         $xml=simplexml_load_file("$url");  
         $progs = $xml->xpath('//programme');
         foreach ($progs as $prog) {
           $title = $prog->xpath('./title/text()')[0];
           $link = (count($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))>0) ? ($prog->xpath('./icon/@src'))[0] : ("No icon");
           echo "Logo: <img src='{$link}'> <br/>" ;
           echo "Title : ".$title. "<br>";
           echo "<br>";
}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With your code I only see the links of the logos,

La hora de La 1 La hora política: https://www.movistarplus.es/recorte/n/caratula4/MTVEP2071537

I want to see the logos

Comment: @Myky Then I'm not sure what you're talking about. Can you give me an example of a title with what you consider the related logo?

Comment: like this https://ibb.co/fDrMFmG

Comment: Here come the icon (logo) and program information what is playing now

Comment: This is the code I have at the moment, but I can't parse the icon(logo)

Comment: I have edited the code in the entry, it looks like this
https://ibb.co/WkD9ZJ0

Comment: @Myky See edit; is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I found that code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637116/parse-xml-tv-listings-find-out-what-is-playing-now but I still can't see the logos, the rest works fine

Comment: @Myky Glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun one. This uses a known hack to convert the xml into an array using `json_decode` and `json_encode`, this makes it easier to work with in my opinion. It also makes extensive use of the `DateTime` object.

```php
$url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HelmerLuzo/TDTChannels_EPG/master/TDTChannels_EPG.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xml = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true); // Hack so we don't have to cast values in the future

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$originalTimezone = 'Europe/Madrid';
$changeTimezone = 'Australia/Sydney'; // If empty, will not change timezone
//$outputFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s O';
$outputFormat = 'G:i';

$channels = [];
foreach ($xml['channel'] as $channel) {
    $id = $channel['@attributes']['id'];
    $channels[$id]['Display Name'] = $channel['display-name'];
    $channels[$id]['Now Showing'] = [];
}

$now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($originalTimezone));
$programmes = [];
foreach ($xml['programme'] as $programme) {
    $id = $programme['@attributes']['channel'];

    $start = $programme['@attributes']['start'];
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis O', $start);
    if (!empty($changeTimezone))
        $start = $start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($changeTimezone));
    
    $stop = $programme['@attributes']['stop'];
    $stop = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis O', $stop);
    if (!empty($changeTimezone))
        $stop = $stop->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($changeTimezone));

    if ($start < $now && $now < $stop) {
        $nowShowing = [
            'Title' => $programme['title'],
            'Subtitle' => '',
            'Description' => '',
            'Date' => '',
            'Start' => '',
            'Stop' => '',
            'Icon' => '',
        ];
    
        if (isset($programme['sub-title']))
            $nowShowing['Subtitle'] = $programme['sub-title'];

        if (isset($programme['desc']))
            $nowShowing['Description'] = $programme['desc'];
    
        if (isset($programme['date']))
            $nowShowing['Date'] = $programme['date'];

        if (isset($programme['date']))
            $nowShowing['Icon'] = $programme['icon']['@attributes']['src'];

        $nowShowing['Start'] = $start->format($outputFormat);
        $nowShowing['Stop'] = $stop->format($outputFormat);
    
        $channels[$id]['Now Showing'] = $nowShowing;
    }
}

foreach ($channels as $id => $details) {
    echo $details['Now Showing']['Start'] . ' - ' . $details['Now Showing']['Stop'] . '<br>' . 
         'Channel:' . $details['Display Name'] . '<br>' . 
         'Title: ' . $details['Now Showing']['Title'] . '<br>' . 
         'Info: ' . $details['Now Showing']['Subtitle'] . '<br>' . 
         'Description: ' . $details['Now Showing']['Description'] . '<br>' . 
         'Logo: <img src="'.$details['Now Showing']['Icon'].'"/><br><br>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't see the icons, I'm trying like this
echo "Logo : ".'<icon src="' .$item->icon . '/>';
what is wrong here?

Comment: @Myky I have updated the answer to include output similar to your question. It still displays channels that have nothing playing right now but there is plenty for you to edit and learn.